# Grant MS Graph access permissions from one account to others - is it possible?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, user-permissions

My organization has an institutional e-mail account in Outlook 365.

There is a small number of users who are responsible for managing that mailbox, reading, answering, forwarding and sending messages from that account.

I am writing a web application (PHP) to automate some messaging operations, so I implemented access to that account using Microsoft Graph. But this requires to login using that account's credentials, and I wouldn't like to share account's password (which I have) with those users.

Is it possible to to grant permission for those users' accounts so MS-Graph will allow them to read/write/send messages from that account, once they have logged in? If so, how would it done?

If this post lacks some relevant information I'm not remembering now, please comment and I'll edit to add it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use admin consent for that purpose. Administrator can grant access for the entire tenant, and users will not be prompted for consent afterwards

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant

Comment: Hi, thank you. Is there a way I can query AD in order to discover who is an empowered admin for that sake? Then I would contact the one nearest to my branch, if not inside it.